# PHP: foreach an array objects, how to move internal pointer to the next one?

Tags: php

I need to loop and array of objects. In some cases, inside the loop, I need to move the internal pointer to the next element in the array. How do I do that?

```
foreach($objects as $object)
{
   // TODO: move internal pointer to next one?
   // next($objects) doesn't work
}
```

Comment: `continue`? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: There is no function `move()` and in fact I dont get, what you want. `foreach` iterates over all entries of an array. So what do you mean by "move internal pointer"? with `foreach` you dont have to take care of the pointer (unlike next(), current(), ...)

Comment: @mhitza: say there are 10 objects in the array and i am on the 5th one. i want to advance the pointer such that the next iteration moves me to the 7th one on the next iteration.

Comment: @kingcrunch: sorry, I meant next()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't move the array pointer, but you can [skip the iteration](http://php.net/continue):

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    if (!interesting($object)) {
        continue;
    }

    // business as usual
}
```

If you need to decide whether to skip the *next* iteration, you can do something like this:

```
$skip = false;

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    if ($skip) {
        $skip = false;
        continue;
    }

    // business as usual

    if (/* something or other */) {
        $skip = true;
    }
}
```

I'd first check if there isn't any better logic to express what you want though. If there isn't, [@netcoder's `list each` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811346/php-foreach-an-array-objects-how-to-move-internal-pointer-to-the-next-one/4811471#4811471) is the more concise way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

As previously mentioned, you can use a `for` loop (only if you have numeric keys though) or `continue`. Another alternative is to use the `list` and `each` iteration method which allows you to move the array pointer with `next`, `prev`, etc. (as it does not create a copy of the array like `foreach` does):

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);

while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
   echo $value;
   next($array);
}
```

Will output:

```
024
```

Answer (score 0):

[next($objects)](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php)

*next — Advance the internal array pointer of an array*

Comment: And what array might you be wanting to advance the internal pointer of? :)

Comment: @deceze, that which the op asked about *"I need to move the internal pointer to the next element in the array. "*

Comment: @deceze, oh, foreach() does not update the internal pointers (does in perl), thanks.

Comment: @Dagon actually `foreach` *does* update the internal pointer of the array it iterates over. It is specified so in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, second note from the top, the one that elaborates on using array references. It is just that, by default `foreach` works with a copy of the array variable one specifies, and thus the pointers of the original array are unalatered, as you say. But only if its a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Now, that I understand, what you want ;), two other solutions

```
$c = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i += 2) {
  $item = $array[$i];
}

foreach (range(0, count($array), 2) as $i) {
  $item = $array[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop, like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
{
    echo $array[$i]->objectParameter;
    $i++; //move internal pointer
    echo $array[$i]->objectParameter;
    $i++; //move internal pointer again
    echo $array[$i]->objectParameter;
    //$i++; //no need for this because for loop does that
}
```